# Проверить EXE на возможность запуска

Tags: delphi, defender

Бывают случаи, когда доступ к какому-либо EXE-файлу блокируется защитником Windows. При попытке его запустить вручную, появляется ошибка как на скриншоте. Если запускать такой файл програмно через функцию ShellExecute, то возвращается код ошибки 5 (Отказано в доступе).

Вопрос, можно ли какой-то функцией определить возможен ли запуск определенного EXE **при этом не запуская его**?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно попробовать открыть его на чтение и прочитать из него немного данных. Если файл заблокирован антивирусом, то, по идее, читать из него тот тоже не даст.